# Как настрить htaccess rewriterule чтобы скрыть реальные пути адресов к файлам?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как настроить `htaccess rewriterule` чтобы скрыть реальные пути адресов к файлам, путём переадресации к 403 или index, если не одно из правил не подходит? То есть, необходимо запретить просмотр документа по истинному адресу.

Я пытаюсь так, но ен получается:

```
# Создание дружественных ссылок
  RewriteEngine On

  # Правило номер 1
  RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ v1/site/index.php?r=index/$1 [L]

  # Правило номер 2
  RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ v1/site/ride.php?r=index/$1 [L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v1/site/index.php?r=index [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpeeg|jpg|png|css|js) index.php

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan То есть, необходимо запретить просмотр документа по истинному адресу, включая php

Comment: Нет ,запретить все документы которые не заканчиваются (gif|jpeeg|jpg|png|css|js) .Знак & забыл

RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpeeg|jpg|png|css|js)$ index.php

Comment: @Большео спасио, Вам. Я просто имел в виду запретить ссылки на реально существующии адреса. Согласно правилу номер один - Правило номер 1 - при обращении к серверу с адреса articles/event RewriteRule нас перкинут на реально существующий адрес. Но, мы и сами на него можем перейти, если его введём в адресную строку браузера. Вот как бы запретить чтобы на такие адреса, нельзя было переходить. Я просто хочу сохранить в приватности все пути в страницам. И сделать дружественные адреса. Спасибо.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan к сожалению не работает. А если после первог оправила убрать [L], то работает так  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ basic/web/index.php?r=index [L] Но тогда первое правило уже не будет работать.

Comment: Я вот думаю как решить это.Я так ненавижу эти RegExp выражения  :))

Comment: Тут почитай -  25 правил .htaccess, которые должен знать каждый web-разработчик http://blogerator.ru/page/fajl-primery-htaccess-redirekt-dostup

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan Большое спасибо. Я это уже читал, и еще прочиту.

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan  Мне кажется тут дело не в регулярках, а в этом часте кода [L]